# How to make gzip from xml file using WSO2 ESB?

Tags: xml, wso2, gzip

I am trying to compress my xml file that I am writing to system disk using gzip. Can this be achieved using WSO2 ESB? My current configuration is this:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test" context="/test">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/test*">
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint template="TestEndpoint"/>
         </call>
         <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
                   value="test.xml')"
                   scope="transport"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="Content-Encoding" value="gzip" scope="transport"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="vfs:file:///home/esb/test"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: configuration seems ok. are you getting an error?

Comment: No, this configuration generates just xml file, I want it to be archived as gzip.

Comment: So you need to create an gz archive with the test.xml file inside it?.

Comment: Yes, I want that xml file to be in gz archive.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no out of the box method to do that. But as a work around you can do the following

1. Write a custom class mediator to zip some content (to archive saved xml file In this case).
2. Using the existing sequence Save the file to file system using VFS transport.
3. In the sequence invoke the class mediator after calling the VFS endpoint.

You can use [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Class+Mediator) to write a class mediator.

Hope this helps.